# Not displaying cookie count correctly

Tags: php, cookies

I have one file `basket.php` that displays the count perfectly, but in the other php file `product.php` it always displays 0 the codings are below:

basket.php

```
<?php
//include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");

if (isset($_COOKIE["products"])) {
    //Count of all products in basket
    $BasketCount = count($_COOKIE['products']);
  //Loop through and get each cookie
    foreach ($_COOKIE['products'] as $name) {
        $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
        echo "$name <a href='remove.php?remove=$name'>Click here to remove from basket</a> <br />\n";
    }
    echo "Basket Count: $BasketCount";

}else{
    echo "Basket is empty";
}
?>
```

product.php
(just the line that gets the basket count)

```
$basketcount = count($_COOKIE['products']);
```

Here is how i set the cookies

addtobasket.php

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");

$product = $_GET['p'];

setcookie("products[$product]", $product);


echo "$product added to basket";
//Show current basket products


?>
```

Comment: Can you show the result of a `var_dump('$BasketCount');` ?

Answer (score 1):

May be issue with path - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php, `$path` parameter. Or domain.

Comment: i can see the count in basket.php

Comment: And your product.php in the same directory? Try setting `$path` to "/" anyway.

Comment: Please, read documentation by the link a posted about `$path` parameter - `The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.`

Answer (score 1):

Not the actual answer, but nevertheless related:

Assuming you're making a commercial website with a basket/shopping cart system, I would advice this:
**DO NOT RELY ON COOKIES**, never. It's stored on client side and can be modified easily. Moreover some browser simply refuses them, and thus your basket won't work.

Use `$_SESSION[]` instead, they only store the identifier client side. Safer, both against hacking code flaws and anything.

Comment: Why cannot he store information about products that on basket in cookies? It is a matter of security only when checking out. There must me some validations. Moreover, session variables are in potential risk of hijacking too.

Comment: Yes all the cookie stores is the product id which is simply a number, and then the checkout matches the number to the price and product name etc

Comment: Sure, but many browser will simply refuse them. Aside security, there is a flexibility reason: no domain, expiration or whatever to take care of. `$_SESSION["product"]=$myProductTab` is way simplier than a call to `setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )`.

Comment: I agree with cafeein, `$_SESSION` is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are running product.php before cookie is set..

other than that code is fine to me.

or you can check cookie is set or not by this code..

if(isset($_COOKIE['products'][$product])){

```
  echo "cookie is set..";
```

}

so that you will have exact idea..

Comment: but the thing is im not for instance say i have a cookie, i can see the count is 1 in basket.php so i refresh the product.php page and its still 0